# Hide checker (if true) in a interactive PDF with custom checkbox created with inDesign

Tags: checkbox, adobe, adobe-indesign, checkmark

I got a problem with checkbox field using Adobe Indesign.

I want an image to become my checkbox button and also change the image after clicking. Unfortunately, after clicking on this button the image changes properly, but it also adds checker (check sign) in the middle of the picture. Can't see to overcome this.

It looks like this:
[checkmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evZjx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using two buttons for that. One hiding the opposite and vice-versa. Here is an example:

[image]

And here is a link to the package :

http://www.filedropper.com/dossieronoff

And here is a link to a demo PDF:
http://www.filedropper.com/onoff

Comment: Actually it helped when I open this pdf using Google Chrome, but on th other hand it won't work on Preview (MacOS) and Safari

Comment: Preview is known as discarding interactive contents. It all depends on PDF readers.